# EDMX file does not update Stored procedure but tables updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

When I am updating my .EDMX file with option "Update Model From Database" at that time I am able to select new stored procedures but after model or complex type is not  updated.I am getting only tables, not  the stored procedures / functions. Visual Studio showing not responding and freezes after some time

Comment: Which visual studio version you are used.

Comment: visual Studio 2012

Comment: at a time either table or stored proc can be updated. once update process is completed Visual studio update Wizard will not respond

Comment: Ok Sreelal if you want to add something new in updating EDMX then it required to add and if you want to refresh or update in existing then it required to refresh you can do these at time one try it.

Comment: After adding tables in edmx,i cannot add stored procs.The update wizard will not respond and it takes hours and the application gets closed after taking so much time

Comment: it depend on your system do one thing delete your edmx and add it again and these time select both store procedure and tables. Visual studio 2012 sometime gives problem but it will solve try.

Comment: tried but the update wizard will not respond and it takes hours

Comment: try to open project in visual studio 2013 and close your computer unwanted process and then add entity framework

Comment: no changes found